# Github Action cache restored gradle cache when it shouldn't have

Tags: github, gradle, caching, github-actions

So [this build ran](https://github.com/xenoterracide/iw-ppm-backend/runs/3406622105?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:109), and you can see it restoring the cache.

```
##[debug]Downloading segment at offset 0 with length 905929557...
```

Which makes no sense to me, this is my action cache definition

```yaml
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: |
          ~/.gradle/caches
          ~/.gradle/wrapper
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-
```

I added this whole file `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/ppm.coverage.gradle.kts`, which has never existed in this project before. I also modified other `gradle.kts` files in the same directory.

This caused the build to pass when it shouldn't have, as the new code checks to see if tests exist, and fails the build if they don't, and there were projects without tests.

How was it able to restore a cache if my `hashFiles` changed?  If anyone should also know why the Gradle build cache wasn't invalidated in a way that required all projects applying the changed plugins to rerun, that'd be great to know.

Comment: Why wouldn't it restore the cache? Your restore key doesn't include the hashed Gradle files, so it just gets the latest.

Comment: @jonrsharpe huh, I don't even know where I got the idea of a restore key from.... I thought (somewhere along the line) that that was the key to restore, but it looks like that's what you restore if it doesn't otherwise match the key. Am I right?